# Angular PWA Offline login

Tags: angular, authentication, progressive-web-apps, offline

I am developing a PWA with Angular and I come across a scenario that has not been presented to me until now. We have the following requirements:

- The application will be used both online and offline
- The device on which the application will be run can be used by different users depending on the day or shift
- When accessing the application, whether there is connectivity or not, the **user must log in** in some way to identify which user is using it.
- In online mode Azure AD is used for the authentication flow

Taking into account that we cannot download credentials to the client side for many reasons, we have thought that the user, in addition to their Azure AD credentials, has a PIN code. This data could be downloaded to the client side. Once connectivity is restored, the user must also sign in to Azure AD.

Could anyone who has had to face this challenge know how he/she solved it?

Or if someone has a better idea, of course, it will be welcomed.

Thank you.